# Check if set: $\{0, 1, 2, 2^2, ..., 2^{15} \pmod {17}\}$ forms a complete set of residues.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

> Check if the set of numbers : $\{0, 1, 2, 2^2, ..., 2^{15} \pmod {17}\}$ form a complete set of residues.

My simple question:  is there any short route to find the answer, rather than checking it individually. I mean that if there is any property that can be used to achieve the same.

Comment: $2^4\equiv -1\pmod{17}$ gives that the order of $2$ in $\mathbb{Z}/(17\mathbb{Z})^*$ is eight. It follows that the answer is *no, they don't*.

Comment: Asking a good question and eliciting responses should also attract votes (positive, though).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is to realize that for $0, 1=2^0; 2^1, ... 2^{15}$ to be complete residue system, the $2^k$ must be distinct.  And if they *aren't* distinct then there must be $2^a \equiv 2^b$ for some $a \ne b$.  (Or some $2^k \equiv 0 \mod 17$ but that means $17|2^k$ and that $2^{m;m\ge k} \equiv 0 \mod 17$ and that's obviously not the case.

If $a< b$ and $2^a \equiv 2^b \mod 17$ then $2^a(2^{a-b}-1) \equiv 0 \mod 17$ so $17|2^a(2^{a-b}-1)$ so $2^{k=a-b} \equiv 1 \mod 17$ for some $k$.

A little intuition should make us think that $b|16$.  Why is that intuitive? Well, because if $2^0 \equiv 1\mod 17$ then $2^k\equiv 2^{2k} \equiv 2^{3k} \equiv 1 \mod 17$ will go in cycles. And as there are only $17$ residue classes and $0$ is not an equivalency class of a power of $2$ there are $16$ non-zero equivalency classes.  That's not hard and fast but it should be an intuitive thought.

So try to test $2^8, 2^4, 2^2, 2^1$.  As $2^4 = 16\equiv -1$ we have $2^8 \equiv 1 \mod 17$ and so the $2^0, ...., 2^{15}$ are not distinct.

It's not a complete residue system.

Comment: Thanks for showing the thought process too, rather than a clean solution.

Comment: I hope you meant in 2nd para. : "$...\mod 17$ then $2^b(2^{a-b}-1)\equiv 0 \mod 17$ so $17 | 2^a(2^{a-b} -1$) so $2^{k=a-b} \equiv 1 \mod 17$ for some $k$." Also, I hope that having $2^{a-b}$ a negative quantity (as $a \lt b$) does not matter for modulo arithmetic.

Comment: Your argument for the divisibility of $16 $ by $b$ is incomplete (at least I feel so). You have shown that if $0$ is an equivalence class, then all powers of $2^k$ will cycle, which is also not complete, I feel you left the 'necessary' part of that. Please help me more, so that either it is a rigorous (& intuitive) proof; or I am able to convert it to that.

Answer (score 3):

Note that $2^4=16\equiv-1\pmod{17}$ and that therefore $2^8\equiv1\pmod{17}$. So, the answer is negative.

Comment: But, this also means that no shortcut is possible. For larger set of values, any clue to a possible short approach. I mean that anything - that even uses some pattern, etc.

Comment: @jiten Right now, I can't think of any.

Comment: If you know Fermat's little theorem,  $b^{phi(n)} \equiv 1 \mod n$ if $\gcd(b,n) = 1$.  And if $b^k \equiv 1 \mod n$ then $k|\phi(n)$ (or $k \ge \phi(n)$ but we aren't considering those).  So just check the $k|\phi(n)$  so for example to check if $0, 1, 3^1, .... 3^{96}$ is residue class mod 97. Check if $3^{46} \equiv 1 \mod 97$. If not check $3^{4}$  If not then it is a complete residue class.

Comment: @fleablood I am not clear about the last line of your kind response. You have first checked for power $= 46$, then stated: "If not, then check for power $ = 4$". I request more elaboration.

Comment: @jiten the shortcut is that $2$ is a quadratic residue modulo $17.$ The Legendre symbol is $(2|17)= 1.$

Comment: @WillJagy Can you please link your answer and that of fleablood. I will read what you said,but linking the two can be more insightful.

Comment: $3^{96}\equiv 1 \mod 97$.  So if $3^k \equiv 1 \mod 97$ and $k \le 96$ then $k|96$.  So $k = 1, 2, 4, 23, 46$ or $96$ or... oh, crap.  $96 \ne 2*46...$   .... hold on let me type a better answer.

Comment: $3^{96}\equiv 1 \mod 97$ so if $3^{k;k< 96}\equiv 1 \mod 97$ then $k|96$.  Start the the highest powers as they are most likely to give us insight.  $3^{48} \equiv ... $ of course the are also the hardest...$3^3\equiv 27$.  $3^6 \equiv 81*9=729\equiv 50$.  $3^{12}\equiv 2500\equiv 75$.  $3^{24}\equiv -1$ so $3^{48} \equiv 1 \mod 97$.  $0,1,3,9.... 3^{95}$ are not a complete residue set.

Comment: For the most part $m= b^{\frac {\phi(n)}2}\equiv \pm 1$ as $m^2 \equiv 1 \mod 97$.  That needs to be proven but it shouldn't be surprising.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to check whether $2^8\equiv 1 \bmod 17$. If it is, the answer is no - if it is not, the answer is yes.

Here, $2^8\equiv 1 \bmod 17$, so the answer is no.

Why do you only need to check that one power? Since [$\phi(17)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function)${} = 16=2^4$, the multiplicative order of every residue must divide $16$ with only [primitive roots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_root_modulo_n) (whose powers form the desired complete set of non-zero residues) having order $16$. Because $2$ is the only prime factor of $16$, the residues $a$ that are not primitive roots must therefore have $a^8\equiv 1 \bmod 17$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for that.

Comment: In general for a prime $p$, any residues $a$ that are not primitive roots will have one or more of  $a^{\large (p-1)/f_i}\equiv 1 \bmod p$, where $\{f_i\}$ are the prime factors of $p{-}1$.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative approach: $p=17$ is a prime $\equiv 1\pmod{8}$, hence $\left(\frac{2}{p}\right)=1$ and $2$ cannot be a generator of $\mathbb{Z}/(17\mathbb{Z})^*$, since it is a quadratic residue. It follows that the answer is negative.

Vice-versa, if $2$ is replaced by any non-quadratic residue $\!\!\pmod{17}$, the answer is positive.